# Github API endpoint not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

We're building a node application where we get the issues for a particular authenticated user from the Github API endpoint api.github.com/user/issues.

This isn't working, and when we test the Github API endpoint in postman (https://www.getpostman.com/), we receive the same message:

```
{
"message": "Not Found",
"documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

If anyone has experience using this endpoint we would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there may be a problem with your authentication token. Try using basic authentication when sending the request to the Github API in Postman.